# How can I put together my different react fragments to avoid "element type is invalid error" when rendering my APP?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

```js
/*
  App.js
*/
import React, { 
       Suspense, 
       useRef, 
       useEffect 
       } from "react"
import { 
       Canvas, 
       Dom 
       } from "react-three-fiber"
import state from "./Store"

import {Pages} from "./Pages"
import {Startup} from "./Startup"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  const scrollArea = useRef()
  const onScroll = (e) => (state.top.current = e.target.scrollTop)
  useEffect(() => void onScroll({ target: scrollArea.current }), [])
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas className="canvas" orthographic camera={{ zoom: state.zoom, position: [0, 0, 500] }}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Dom center className="loading" children="Loading..." />}>
          <Pages />
          <Startup />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      <div className="scrollArea" ref={scrollArea} onScroll={onScroll}>
        <div style={{ height: `${state.pages * 100}vh` }} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I run de App i get the error. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

```js
/*
   Pages.js
*/
import React from "react"
import {  Dom, useLoader } from "react-three-fiber"
import { TextureLoader, LinearFilter } from "three"
import { Block, useBlock } from "./Blocks"
import {Content} from "./Content"
import {Stripe} from "./Stripe"
import {Cross} from "./Cross"
import state from "./Store"

function Pages() {
    const textures = useLoader(TextureLoader, state.images)
    const [img1, img2, img3] = textures.map(
      texture => (((texture.minFilter = LinearFilter), texture))
    )
  
  
    const { contentMaxWidth, mobile } = useBlock()
    const aspect = 1.75
    const pixelWidth = contentMaxWidth * state.zoom
    return (
      <>
        {/* First section */}
        <Block factor={1.5} offset={0}>
          <Content left map={img1}>
            <Dom style={{ width: pixelWidth / (mobile ? 1 : 2), textAlign: "left" }} position={[-contentMaxWidth / 2, -contentMaxWidth / 2 / aspect - 0.4, 1]}>
              The substance can take you to heaven but it can also take you to hell.
            </Dom>
          </Content>
        </Block>
        {/* Second section */}
        <Block factor={2.0} offset={1}>
          <Content map={img2}>
            <Dom style={{ width: pixelWidth / (mobile ? 1 : 2), textAlign: "right" }} position={[mobile ? -contentMaxWidth / 2 : 0, -contentMaxWidth / 2 / aspect - 0.4, 1]}>
              We’ve found that the people whose EEG doesn’t show any alpha-wave activity when they’re relaxed aren’t likely to respond significantly to the substance.
            </Dom>
          </Content>
        </Block>
        {/* Stripe */}
        <Block factor={-1.0} offset={1}>
          <Stripe />
        </Block>
        {/* Last section */}
        <Block factor={1.5} offset={2}>
          <Content left map={img3}>
            <Block factor={-0.5}>
              <Cross />
            </Block>
            <Dom style={{ width: pixelWidth / (mobile ? 1 : 2), textAlign: "left" }} position={[-contentMaxWidth / 2, -contentMaxWidth / 2 / aspect - 0.4, 1]}>
              Education and enlightenment.
            </Dom>
          </Content>
        </Block>
      </>
    )
  }

export {Pages}
```

```js
/*
  Startup.js
*/
import React  from 'react'
import { useRef, useFrame } from 'react'
import lerp from 'lerp'

function Startup() {
    const ref = useRef()
    useFrame(() => (ref.current.material.opacity = lerp(ref.current.material.opacity, 0, 0.025)))
    return (
      <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 0, 200]} scale={[100, 100, 1]}>
        <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" />
        <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="#dfdfdf" transparent />
      </mesh>
    )
  }

export {Startup}
```

How can I import all of my fragments to my App.js file and make it render?

```js
/*
  index.js
*/
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

When I run de App i get the error. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Comment: You've certainly forgot to return something from one of your component, maybe in `Block` `Cross` or `Content`

Comment: suggestion : you can use code fences instead of snippets since the snippet feature here is not necessary